# In Pegs and Jokers, is it legal to split a seven card between my peg and my partner's peg?

Tags: pegs-and-jokers

In Pegs and Jokers, there are two teams of three each. Player A has four pegs in the castle and his fifth peg is two holes away from going in to have all pegs in the castle. Player A wants to play a seven card and move his last peg two holes into the castle (he would then have all five pegs in his castle) and use the remaining five moves to advance a peg belonging to his partner to his left. Is this legal?

Comment: No one has addressed our issue. We had player one and partner right outside home. all others in. Player played a seven. She used 3 moves to get her peg home and used 3 more to move partner into home winning the game. Does the number have to be exact to move into home at the end of the game ? That was using 6 out of the seven. No other pegs left on the board.

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on the variant that you're playing. [This site](http://www.pagat.com/misc/pegsandjokers.html) lists the rules that come into play here. First, the basic rules:

> In the basic game, except in special circumstances described below, you may only move your own pegs.
>   ...
>   When playing a 7, you may either move one of your pegs forward 7 holes, or split the 7 between two of your pegs, moving them 1 and 6, 2 and 5 or 3 and 4 holes forwards. Of course the split move can only be made if you have at least two pegs in play.
>   ...
>   When, and only when, all five of your pegs are in the home (safe) position, occupying the five holes of your home track, you use your turn to move the pegs of your left-hand partner, if that player still has playable pegs. If left partner's pegs are also all home, you move the pegs of the next partner around the table who still has playable pegs.

As I read this, the ability to move your partner's pegs depends on the state of the game at the start of your turn. Player A still has pegs out, so he would not be able to split the 7 with his partner's peg; he only has one peg out, so he could not split the 7.

If you're using Arizona Rules, then it would be allowed:

> Throughout the game, you may move **any** of the pegs belonging to your team (so for example any of 20 pegs in the 8-player game with 4 on each team). Therefore you may discard without moving only if you are unable to play a card (other than a joker) that moves any of your team's pegs.

and this situation is explicitly mentioned in the North Carolina Rules:

> As in the basic game, you can only move your own pegs until your last peg is home. After that you move the pegs of the partner nearest to your left. You can use a split move to take your last peg home and move your left hand partner's peg with the remainder.

Because it's explicitly mentioned in the last variant, I do not think it is permitted in basic play.

Answer (score 3):

We ordered a Pegs & Jokers board and it came with rules.  It does specify that the 7 or 9 can be split with your partner to the left, when moving your last peg into your castle, as long as that partner has a peg in play.

Answer (score 0):

This would be legal the way we play.  Putting your last peg in the castle using say 3 of a seven and finishing your move by moving your partner's peg on the outside track the rest of the seven say 4. (or any other split of a seven combination).  Our group have agreed to use the "Basic Rules" with one variation (Don't have to use the Left Hand partner, your choice but only one at a time) AND the addition of the Arizona rule of 9 being split( part forward and the other part backwards)  We find this speeds-up the game and makes for a better game.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, we allow a 7 to be split when last peg enters home with any partner. We also use a 2 to switch places with a partner. Makes an interesting game and it speeds up the game, especially when 6 are playing. IL and in FL

Comment: This sounds like a house rule and not an official one. Do you have any evidence to state that this is an official rule and not a house rule?